# ListView OnItemClick PutExtra Method

Tags: android, eclipse, string

I have got listview with many items but my OnItemClickListener does not work. Here is my code.

```
public String mystring;
.
.
.
public void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AlistView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long id) {
            switch(position)
            {
                case 0:
                mystring="A";
                Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Hlavni2.class);
                intent0.putExtra("text1", mystring);
                    break;
                case 1:
                mystring="B";
                intent0 = new Intent();
                intent0.putExtra("text1", mystring);
                startActivity(intent0);
                    break;
                case 2:
                mystring="C";
                intent0=New Intent();
                intent0.putExtra("text1", mystring);
                startActivity(intent0);
                break;
                case 3:
                mystring="D";
                intent0=New Intent();
                intent0.putExtra("text1", mystring);
                startActivity(intent0);
                   break;
                    }
                   }
                  }
                 }
```

What am I doing wrong? When I go by this code it works, but I think its not good, here it is.

```
switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
            mystring="A";
            Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Hlavni2.class);
            intent0.putExtra("text1", mystring);
                        break;
            case 1:
            mystring="B";
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Hlavni2.class);
            intent1.putExtra("text1", mystring);
            startActivity(intent1);
                        break;
            case 2:
            mystring="C";
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Hlavni2.class);
            intent2.putExtra("text1", mystring);
            startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
            case 3:
            mystring="D";
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Hlavni2.class);
            intent3.putExtra("text1", mystring);
            startActivity(intent3);
                       break;
                        }
                       }
                      }
                     }
```

I would like to do it more clearer. Please help me :/.

Comment: "Does not work" --> could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want do first approach you need initialize your `intent` out side of `switch case`

```
 Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Hlavni2.class);
 switch(position)
            {
             case 0:
                mystring="A";
                intent0.putExtra("text1", mystring);
                startActivity(intent0); 
                    break;
             case 1:
                mystring="B";
                intent0.putExtra("text1", mystring);
                startActivity(intent0);
                    break;
             case 2:
                mystring="C";
                intent0.putExtra("text1", mystring);
                startActivity(intent0);
                break;
             case 3:
                mystring="D";
                intent0.putExtra("text1", mystring);
                startActivity(intent0);
                   break;
                    }
                   }
                  }
                 }
```

if you handle all clicked so you can start your activity on `finally` method that called just one time

you initialize your `intent` like:

```
intent0=New Intent();
```

so after this you start activity with this intent, but you want start witch Activity? if you initialize your intent before switch case, then you can use that in your method simply.